# Creating dynamic Tuple

Tags: c#

Are there a good way  to create dynamic number of arguments like:

```
public ??? Tuple<string,?????> returnProperTuple(int NumberOfArgs)
{// if/case
if(NumberOfArgs == 2)
 return new Tuple<string, string>();
...
if(NumberOfArgs == 4)
return new Tuple<string, string, string, string>();
...
}
```

Comment: What? ... it doesn't make any sens ...  return `IEnumerable<string>`

Comment: It depends on your task. Think about any type of collection, maybe it will be better approach.

Comment: Needs details or clarity 1
Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Explain your problem, so we can help you better. Why do you need this?

Comment: Add more details, please. This way it is not clear what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have an unknown number of arguments as you wish as the compiler needs to know certain information about what you are passing and how to link calls to specific method signatures.

If you need a variable number of arguments then you should use some kind of collection instead.
Or if you want the type of argument to be somewhat dynamic or anonymous then you can use an `object` type, which can basically be anything you want.

For example:

```
public IList returnProper(int NumberOfArgs)


public Dictionary<string, object> returnProper(int NumberOfArgs)


public object returnProper(int NumberOfArgs)

public Tuple<string, object> returnProper(int NumberOfArgs)
```